# Store details of a row in an SQLite DB

Tags: database, sqlite

I would like to know how I can store details of a row efficiently in an SQLite DB.
For example:

Main-Table: 
ID | NAME | CITY
1  |  Peter | Paris
2  |  Sarah | New York
3  | Seth  | Chicago

I want to store details about a person in the database but I don't know how I should do that. The problem is that the data could be represented as an Array in a program code but I can't do that in a DB. My though was this one:

table "person_1": (table for storing favorite places in the city)
NAME | ADDRESS
Eiffel Tower | Champ de Mars, 5 Avenue Anatole
Musee du Louvre | Musée du Louvre, 75058 Paris

table "person_2": (same purpose)
NAME | ADDRESS
One World Trade Center | 285 Fulton Street
Statue of Liberty | Liberty Island

And so on with other persons...

Is this the right approach or can I do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by having 2 tables:

Table People:

```
id | name  | city
 1 | Peter | Paris
 2 | Sarah | New York
```

Table Favorite Places:

```
id | person_id | name                   | address
1  | 1         | Eiffel Tower           | Champ de Mars, 5 Avenue Anatole
2  | 1         | Musee du Louvre        | Musée du Louvre, 75058 Paris
3  | 2         | One World Trade Center | 285 Fulton Street
```

This way you can easily select all favorite places belonging to each person.

---

You can even write queries JOINing two tables:

```
SELECT p.name, f.name, f.address
FROM people    AS p
JOIN favorites AS f ON p.id = f.person_id
```

and you'll get:

```
Peter | Eiffel Tower           | Champ de Mars, 5 Avenue Anatole
Peter | Musee du Louvre        | Musée du Louvre, 75058 Paris
Sarah | One World Trade Center | 285 Fulton Street
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to the SQL language, what does this part actually mean and do?: "FROM people AS p JOIN favorites AS f ON f.id = f.person_id"

Comment: `AS something` allows you to use different names for the tables, here I use `people AS p` so I can write `p.name` instead of `people.name`.

Comment: `JOIN` is used to combine tables, there are also `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` etc. that combine tables a bit differently.

Comment: Oh, that's a really nice feature to know, thank you :D

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but isn't that supposed to be `p.id = f.person_id` instead of `f.id = f.person_id` at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Main-Table which stored peoples like;

```
id | name  | address
1  | Peter | Paris
2  | Sarah | New York
```

Favorite_Place table for places like;

```
id | name            | address
1  | Eiffel Tower    | Champ de Mars, 5 Avenue Anatole
2  | Musee du Louvre | Musée du Louvre, 75058 Paris
```

and the middle table something like;

```
person_id | place_id
1         | 1
1         | 2
2         | 1
2         | 2
```

If you design tables something like that, you aren't store favorite places again and again in favorite_place table.

Comment: Good point! This is called a many-to-many relation whereas my solution uses a one-to-many relation.